# Why does the code give me wrong output for an amount? (Change making problem)

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I was trying to solve the coin change problem in which we have to find the minimum number of coins that add up to a specific amount.

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
import sys
denomination = [1,6,10]
amount = 12

def coin_change(amount,denomination):
    coins = 0
    ans = [0]*(amount+1)
    temp = sys.maxsize
    for i in range(len(ans)):
        for j in range(len(denomination)):
            if denomination[j] <= i:
                ans[i] = min(temp, ans[i-denomination[j]]) + 1
    return ans

print(coin_change(amount,denomination))
```

The output is

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3].
```

Why is the last number in the output a 3 for the amount 12? I have gone through the code so many times, but I still don't understand why this happens. It gives 1 for the amount 6, so it should give 2 for the amount 12 instead of 3.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `min(temp, ...)` is a useless call, as you never reduce the value of `temp`. This expression is always going to return the second argument. Obviously you really *need* to compare alternatives and choose the optimal one, so this is wrong.

And that is the reason you get 3. The last denomination that is tried is 10 (when `j` is 2). Before that try, `ans[12]` was actually 2, but it gets overwritten with 3 (10+1+1)!

Here is a correction:

```
import sys
denomination = [1,6,10]
amount = 12

def coin_change(amount,denomination):
    ans = [sys.maxsize]*(amount+1)  # initialise with maximum value
    for i in range(len(ans)):
        for j in range(len(denomination)):
            if denomination[j] <= i:
                if denomination[j] == i:
                    ans[i] = 1  # base case
                else:  # see if we can improve what we have
                    ans[i] = min(ans[i], ans[i-denomination[j]] + 1)
    return ans

print(coin_change(amount,denomination))
```